# encrypt body header email

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, smtp

how do I encrypt the body of the email?
What is it encrypted with, or what is it called. Thank you.
i'm nodejs maybe libary node
a'im use nodemailer
22222222222222222222222222222222222222222

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-Last-TLS-Session-Version: TLSv1.3
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```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you really mean "encrypt", or rather decode the base64-encoded body of the email:

```js
Buffer.from(`PGh0...Pg==`, "base64").toString()
```

gives a nice HTML document.

Comment: Why do you "answer" an unclear no-effort question with spam (_"2222..."_) with an assumption?